# How to use bybit replace api

Tags: python, cryptocurrency

I've to tried to use bybit replace api.
But I can't run that api.

https://github.com/LongandShortio/bybit_api_python/blob/master/rest_api.py

I've tried to use following code.

https://github.com/LongandShortio/bybit_api_python/blob/master/rest_api.py

https://github.com/bybit-exchange/api-connectors/blob/master/official-http/python/test.py

Who can know this solution?